# Cannot invoke "java.time.Clock.instant()" because "this.this$0.clock" is null

Tags: java, mocking, spring-webflux, clock, spring-test

I am writing tests for a java spring boot rest application. I need to mock the clock.
This is the test :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest(controllers = MyController.class)
@Import({MyController.class})
public class Test implements WebTestClientConfigurable {

  
    @Autowired
    private MyController myController;
    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    public static long NOW = System.currentTimeMillis();


    public MockedStatic<Clock> clockMock;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        mockInstant(NOW);
    }


    @AfterEach
    public void close() {
        clockMock.close();
    }

    private void mockInstant(long expected) {
        Clock spyClock = spy(Clock.class);
        clockMock = mockStatic(Clock.class);
        clockMock.when(Clock::systemUTC).thenReturn(spyClock);
        when(spyClock.instant()).thenReturn(Instant.ofEpochSecond(expected));
    }

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    void test() {
        configure(webTestClient)
                .post()
                .uri("/test" )
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .is2xxSuccessful();

    }
}
```

The test is failing because of clock mocking.
I have other tests with the mocking clock that do not use webtestclient and don't fail.
The WebTestClient is :

```
public interface WebTestClientConfigurable {
    default WebTestClient configure(WebTestClient webTestClient) {
        return webTestClient
                .mutate().responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(120))
                .build()  // this is where the test is failing
                .mutateWith(mockJwt()
                        .authorities(new SecurityConfiguration.GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor())
                        .jwt(builder -> builder.claim("myvalue", 1)))
                .mutateWith(csrf());
    }
}
```

The test is failing with this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.time.Clock.instant()" because "this.this$0.clock" is null

    at org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$ExpiredSessionChecker.<init>(InMemoryWebSessionStore.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore.<init>(InMemoryWebSessionStore.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.server.session.DefaultWebSessionManager.<init>(DefaultWebSessionManager.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter.<init>(HttpWebHandlerAdapter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.WebHttpHandlerBuilder.build(WebHttpHandlerBuilder.java:394)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClientBuilder.build(DefaultWebTestClientBuilder.java:285)
    at test.WebTestClientConfigurable.configure(WebTestClientConfigurable.java:15)
```

I have no idea how to fix this. If I don't mock the clock, I don't have the issue.